# how to make the output of an if statement a variable

Tags: php

I am trying to get search a variable for multiple keywords. Then for different keyword it finds, i would like it to echo a different answer. echo should then become a variable, is this possible? for example:

```
if (strpos($PageTitle,'electrical, electrician, security') !== false) {
echo 'Electrical Service';
}

if (strpos($PageTitle,'heating, gas') !== false) {
echo 'Plumbing Service';
}
```

Comment: So just to make it clear here: You want to search multiple words in a string and depending on that you want to print a different output which you want to assign to a variable? If yes, what if 2 words are found in the string, which one do you use? And what is with the second if statement?

Comment: strpos() is not going to work searching for multiple strings. You'd need to do separate strpos() searches

Comment: yes correct, in this case 2words will not be found, keywords will be very specific. second if statement i would like to combine with the first to make an overall statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$search_for = array('Electrical Service' => 'electrical, electrician, security', 'Plumbing Service' => 'heating, gas');

foreach ($search_for as $name=>$term){
 if (strpos($PageTitle,$term) !== false){
  echo $name;
  // add break; here if you want to display only one (first) found
 }
}
```

Something like that.. Create more array elements if you need to.

Comment: *Something like that?* I think this is what OP is asking and not the guy how answers it!

Comment: I put question mark here by mistake. So? What's the big deal? I helped the guy...isn't that most important ?

Comment: seems to always output plumbing when i echo $name